# MongoDB constantly high cpu usage

Tags: mongodb

According to docker container statistics, my mongo database consumes constantly between 250 and 350% cpu. That's pretty impressive since it's a single core system :P

The sad part is that this is my production instance and much more sad is that it has to live until the next prod-backup and thats 3.5 more hours to go.

I tried to do a mongotop but it tells me 0ms stats for all shown collections. Can I do anything else to figure out what's going on?

PS: The db is up for 9 weeks and didn't cause problems.

Comment: and that shows the htop?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is a function called [db.currentOp()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/) which lists the currently running queries with very detailed information, it also includes the duration they have been running (`secs_running`).

You can then use the `currentOp.opid` with [db.killOp()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.killOp/) to kill that query/operation.

If `db.currentOp()` doesn't return any results, because there is no query which went havoc, then there's also [db.setProfilingLevel()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/) which will enable profiling by storing queries into the "local" database. [Here](https://youtu.be/MzLmI8FNB94)'s a "Tutorial" which is from the ["M102: MongoDB for DBAs"](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M102/about) Course.

Further information can also be found in this detailed article ["Troubleshooting MongoDB 100% CPU load and slow queries"](https://medium.com/@igorkhomenko/troubleshooting-mongodb-100-cpu-load-and-slow-queries-da622c6e1339) from Igor Khomenko.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The output is `{ "inprog" : [ ] }` :(

Comment: I think there is some kind of logging you can enable, which then stores queries which take an unusual amount of time into the "local" database. I'll have a look if I find some more information on this.

Comment: Added info about db.setProfilingLevel()

Comment: Okay I figured it out. Someone indeed executed broken queries but in a separate  `mongo` process so I couldn't see it with `db.curentOP()`. Weird. I had to kill the processes itself on the system layer. Anyways, I'll definitely have a look at this profiling level, sounds reasonable to know about it if you run a production mongo :) Thank you Daniel!

Comment: Hey, good for you! I can only recommend the M102 course, it is super informative. But what you're saying sounds pretty strange, because it `db.currentOp()` is independent of the `mongo` shell process as it is executed on the `mongod` server, so it shouldn't matter which connected shell you use. Maybe you just got lucky with the timing in that other `mongo` shell.

Comment: This command will show if there are some batched running queries in mongo.  `mongod --auth --port <port> --dbpath <path>`  E.g.  `mongod --auth --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db/`

Answer (score 22):

The first and more important thing that you need to do is check your kind of queries, for example, in my case I had the same problem and when I checked my logs `tail -f /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` (You can configure this logs in `/etc/mongod.conf`) I only saw the simple queries like  db.brands.find({"field":"value"}) but I checked my indexes in "brands" collections and this field on queries was not indexed (`db.brands.getIndexes()`). The only thing that I did is index this field `db.brands.ensureIndex({name:1},{unique:true})`. Of course make sure if your field is unique because in this example I put as a unique. After that my CPU changed from 100% to 20%.

So I am not saying that is your problem but could be, check your queries before doing some bigger things.

Comment: This was the correct answer for me. Dropped to a constant 95-98% of CPU usage to a fair 10% of peak usage even though I'm using the smallest Azure's VM

Answer (score 0):

In my case one mongodb process was taking 700% cpu, it was 8 cores cpu server.After analysing mongodb logs i realised data fetch queries to some collections were creating this issue.Adding indexes to these collections solved my problem.
Below are some helpful commands:

- To check mongodb logs:

  `tail -f /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log`
- To check indexes of collections:

  `db.collections.getIndexes()`
- To create new index:

  `db.collections.createIndex({field_name:1})`

Make sure this field has unique values.