# MongoDB high cpu usage/long read time

Tags: mongodb, perl

I am a new user of MongoDB, and I am hoping to get pointed in the right direction. I will provide any further needed information I have missed as this question develops.

I am using a Perl program to upload and annotate/modify documents to a/in a MongoDB database via the MongoDB cpan module. Indexes are being used (I believe) for this program, but the problem I have is that reading from MongoDB takes increasingly long. Based on mongotop, it takes ~500 ms to read and only 10-15 ms to write. After allowing the program to run for a considerable amount of time, the read time increases significantly, taking more then 3000+ ms after many hours of running.

Monitoring the program while its running using top, Perl starts out at around 10-20% CPU usage and MongoDB starts at 70-90% CPU usage. While running, within a few minutes Perl drops below 5% and mongoDB is 90-95%. After running for a much longer period of time (12+ hours), MongoDB is ~98% CPU usage while Perl is around 0.3%, but only pops up every 5-10 seconds in top.

Based on this trend, an indexing issue seems very likely but I am not sure how to check this, and all I know is that the appropriate indexes are at least made, but not necessarily being used.

**Additional information:**

```
$ ulimit -a    
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0    
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited 
scheduling priority             (-e) 0    
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited    
pending signals                 (-i) 19209    
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64    
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited    
open files                      (-n) 1024 
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8    
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200    
real-time priority              (-r) 0    
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192    
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited    
max user processes              (-u) 19209
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited    
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

- As the program runs, I see that the indexSize and dataSize change (via db.stats() in the Mongo shell), which makes me think that they are at least being used to some degree
- Is this something that could be affected by the power of my computer? I am under the impression that indexing should make a lot of this process very manageable for the computer

Comment: It would be good to have a rough estimate of how much data your program processes per unit of time and what it does with it — just formatting vs. encrypting things, for example, can make a huge performance difference. Also, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34951683/mongodb-constantly-high-cpu-usage) *might* help.

Comment: I actually found the source of the problem: 

The program I am running is modular and all but 1 index is created within the components of the program I had been using. Once I found the problem index call, I was able to solve it and the read/write time stayed ~50ms total and havent been increasing linearly as they had been.

Comment: Glad you got it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds a lot like it could be doing a collection scan rather than using the index.  I.e. as your collection grows, the reads are getting slower.

If you're using the `find` method, you can run `explain` on the resulting cursor to get information on how the query would execute.

Here's a trivial example:

```
use MongoDB;
use JSON::MaybeXS;

my $coll = MongoDB->connect->ns("test.foo");
$coll->drop();
$coll->insert_one({x => $_}) for 1 .. 1000;

my $cursor = $coll->find({x => 42});
my $diag = $cursor->explain;

my $json = JSON::MaybeXS->new(
    allow_blessed => 1, convert_blessed => 1, pretty => 1, canonical => 1
);

print $json->encode($diag->{queryPlanner}{winningPlan});
```

Looking at just the 'winningPlan' part of the output you can see 'COLLSCAN':

```
{
   "direction" : "forward",
   "filter" : {
      "x" : {
         "$eq" : 42
      }
   },
   "stage" : "COLLSCAN"
}
```

Now I'll do it again, but first creating an index on 'x' before the insertions with `$coll->indexes->create_one([x => 1])`.  You can see in the output that the query plan is now using the index (IXSCAN).

```
{
   "inputStage" : {
      "direction" : "forward",
      "indexBounds" : {
         "x" : [
            "[42, 42]"
         ]
      },
      "indexName" : "x_1",
      "indexVersion" : 2,
      "isMultiKey" : false,
      "isPartial" : false,
      "isSparse" : false,
      "isUnique" : false,
      "keyPattern" : {
         "x" : 1
      },
      "multiKeyPaths" : {
         "x" : []
      },
      "stage" : "IXSCAN"
   },
   "stage" : "FETCH"
}
```

There's a lot more you can discover from the full 'explain' output.  You can watch a great video from MongoDB World 2016 to learn more about it: [Deciphering Explain Output](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=youtu.be&v=9dKVdDR3K3E).